# Objective-C, using protocol to access datasource

Tags: objective-c, protocols, datasource

I'm using the MVC model but I cannot get the data needed for the View, I am trying to use a data source since a View should never own its data. Typically, a protocol is used to create a data source.

- I have a MVC: CalculatorBrain.[hm] - CalculatorViewController.[hm] - (view is .xib)
- I also have MVC: GraphingView - GraphingViewController - (model is the data I can't get)

The goal is: when I press a button on the calculator, it draws the function (e.g.: x+5=) that is currently in it's display. The calculator part takes care of the expression/function, the display, etc while the graphing part should draw. **CalculatorViewController should be the GraphingView's source**, but the data always stays null.

This is GraphingView.h with the declaration of the protocol :

```
@class GraphingView;

@protocol GraphingViewSource
- (float)getDataPoints:(GraphingView *)requestor;
@end

@interface GraphingView : UIView {
    id <GraphingViewSource> source;
}

@property (assign) id <GraphingViewSource> source;

@end
```

CalculatorViewController.m implements the protocol by implementing the getDataPoints: method. Header of CalculationViewController.h :

```
@interface CalculatorViewController : UIViewController <GraphingViewSource>
```

Pressing the button which should set up the data source :

```
- (IBAction)graphPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    GraphingViewController *graphingVC = [[GraphingViewController alloc] init];
    graphingVC.graphingView.source = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:graphingVC animated:YES];
    [graphingVC release];
}
```

Pressing the button brings up the new view nicely etc, but following line of code only returns null (inside GraphingView.m) :

```
float result = [self.source getDataPoints:self];
```

It seems, I cannot access my data source...

Comment: Using debugging, what do you see when calling `[self.source getDataPoints:self]`? Does it step into your `CalculatorViewController`, or is `source` nil?

Comment: I does not step into CalculatorViewcontroller indeed, source is 0x0...

Comment: Then `graphingVC.graphingView` is probably `nil` at the time you set the `source`. Is there a xib for this or do you create the views in code?

Comment: There is a xib for that, added a UIView in Interface Builder and set its class to GraphingView..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments it seems that `graphingView` is `nil` at the time you are trying to set its source.

If there is a xib for the view controller, you should be doing this:

```
GraphingViewController *graphingVC = [[GraphingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GraphingViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Instead of a plain `init`.

This will create and instantiate all of your view objects so they are available to have properties set before you present the view controller.

Comment: graphingView still being empty when trying to set it's source.

Comment: Then you may not be connecting up its outlet properly in interface builder.

Comment: I can set the source inside viewDidLoad: in GraphingViewCalculator but I need that very same object of CalculatorViewController, creating a new one will not work...

edit: noticed your comment too late, checking IB now

Comment: Then you might have to set source as a property on the GraphingViewController as well, then pass it on further to the view itself.